# Use single UITableViewCell subclass across multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

So I have this `UITableViewCell` subclass that has some really complicated logics in it - it triggers some actions in `UIViewController` it's actually attached to. Of course the cell is not aware of its `UIViewController` but I still navigate to it like this:

```
UITabBarController *tabVC = (UITabBarController *)appDelegate.rootVC.centerPanel;
SGFirstTabViewController *firstTab1 = [tabVC.viewControllers firstObject];

[firstTab1 reloadCell:self];
```

The thing is now that I want to use the same subclass of `UITableViewCell` around about 5 different `UIViewControllers`.

What's the best way to do this? I will almost never know what is the `UITableViewCell's` VC is and I simply can't create 5 different cell subclasses with the same code over and over. What's the best way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is perhaps some misunderstanding in the role of the cell in the model-view-controller programming pattern.

The cell should not reload itself but it should be told to reload by the view controller that controls it. The reload code in the cell can stay the same.

So, rather than the cell having to find out which one its view controller is, have the view controller listen to the cell action (e.g. via delegate methods) and fill it with the appropriate reload data as directed.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect idea. So how about putting all this delegate stuff in multiple VCs, won't it make it conflicting for them to find out what action for what VC has been triggered?

Comment: If one cell is supposed to trigger actions to various other VCs, you need a coupling mechanism that is not so tight: `NSNotificationCenter`! Also, don't use cells if you do not have a table view.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. Two very useful and bright ideas to support the MVC model)